# access to intermediary return values in a clojure monad

Tags: clojure, monads

I would like to compose functions of the following type:

```
; input is a value x and the return value is a vector. 
(defn f [x] [x *whatever*])
```

In order to compose such functions I use such a monad:

```
(require '[clojure.algo.monads :as m])
(m/defmonad example-m
   [m-result (fn [v] v)
    m-bind   (fn [[v k] f]
              (f v) )])
```

Using the following 2 example functions,

```
(defn f1 [s] [(inc s) :f1])
(defn f2 [s] [(* 2 s) :f2])
```

evaluating the monad returns the correct value:

```
(m/domonad example-m [x1 [4 1] 
                      x2 (f1 x1) 
                      x3 (f2 x2) 
                      ] x3) ; => [10 :f2]
```

However, I am interested to evaluate the following expression:

```
(m/domonad example-m [x1 [4 1] 
                      x2 (f1 x1) 
                      x3 (f2 x2) 
                      ] [x1 x2 x3]) ; => [4 5 10]
```

I was expecting `[[4 1] [5 :f1] [10 :f2]]`

Can I use the monad to solve this problem or do I need to fallback to a macro?

*EDIT*:

I have analyzed the source of the problem in a bit more detail. The monad library expands the code above into:

```
(m-bind [4 1] 
        (fn [x1] 
          (m-bind (f1 x1) 
                  (fn [x2] 
                    (m-bind (f2 x2) 
                            (fn [x3] 
                              (m-result [x1 x2 x3])))))))
```

This shows that the variables `x1`, `x2`, `x3` cannot be monadic values but must be the 'real' values. Hence the behavior.

A quick modification of m-bind

```
(defn m-bind   [[v k ] f]
               [(f v) k])
```

yields `[[[[4 5 10] :f2] :f1] 1]`. I guess the solution is in the `m-result` function which has to unwrap this nested structure.

Comment: Is your goal just to compose functions of that type, or is it to use a monad to compose functions of that type?

Comment: My goal is compose functions of that type and it looks like the monad could be possible solution

Comment: Maybe I should be more precise: I would like to compose functions of such a type but need access to the intermediary values. I will need those to perform a final calculation. Basically I need a let-form with monadic composition.

Comment: Your definitions of `result` and `bind` don't satisfy any of the [monad laws](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Monad_laws), so bad stuff of some kind is likely to happen eventually. The definition of `bind` is fine, but `result` is all wrong, and can't be a legal definition for *any* monad. A version of `result` that matches this `bind` would be something like: `[m-result (fn [v] [v :none])]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be looking for something like the Writer monad, where the intermediate functions return a "primary" value and possibly some additional log information. A Clojure implementation of `result` and `bind` for this monad might look something like this (not using any of the monad tools, just writing it ourselves with functions):

```
(letfn [(m-result [v]
          [v []])
        (m-bind [[v logs] f]
          (let [[v' logs'] (f v)]
            [v' (into logs logs')]))
        (tell [log]
          (fn [x]
            [x [[x log]]]))
        (f1 [s]
          (m-bind (m-result (inc s))
                  (tell :f1)))
        (f2 [s]
          (m-bind (m-result (* 2 s))
                  (tell :f2)))]    
  (m-bind (m-result 4)
          (fn step [x1]
            (m-bind (f1 x1) f2))))
```

Here result, bind, and tell are generic definitions useful for any application of this writer; f1 and f2 are as defined in your question but changed a bit to make them fit the revised monad; and the body of the letfn (starting with m-bind) is the desugared form of your original m-do expression.

The idea is to make a monadic value be a pair, containing (a) the value being worked on, and (b) a list of intermediate states, along with labels for each state, like :f1. bind's job is to call f on just the (a) part of that pair, and concatenate the list of "logged" states. Then in your do-expr, you start with (result 4) so that you have a proper monadic value, and then bind a number of monadic functions to it. And indeed what gets returned from this whole thing is `[10 [[5 :f1] [10 :f2]]]`: "the final value was 10, and here are all the intermediate values along with their labels, in case you wanted those too".

My syntax for this looks somewhat primitive, for two reasons: (1) I wanted to remind you that this is all just working with functions, and if you're writing your own monad you should understand them well enough to do it without using a monad library (although you'll want to use the library in practice); and (2) because now it's a pasteable, runnable snippet with no other dependencies. If you want to shoehorn all this into the contrib.monads framework, you'll probably find a definition of `tell` that's more suitable in that context than mine is, such that it's suitable for use as a monadic value instead of as a binding function.

**Edit**: Note that it looks kinda gross that I had to modify `f1` and `f2` to make them participate in our writer monad, but you could define a general `lift-writer` function that wraps an existing function, and then wrap your "dumb" functions in that, like so:

```
(defn lift-writer [f]
  (fn [s]
    (let [[ret label] (f s)]
      (m-bind (m-result ret) (tell label)))))

(def f1* (lift-writer f1 :f1))
(def f2* (lift-writer f2 :f2))
```

and then use those lifted versions instead in the m-do.

Comment: Thank you for taking time and giving me this good answer. The writer monad seems to be a very clean solution for retrieving the intermediary values. I realize that the monad is really a generalization of a binding form and the semantics are not quite the same. Looking at the binding form in my example makes me think that the values `x1, x2` etc. are regular bindings. When you look at the generated code you'll see that they are just input arguments. The outer code can impossibly bind to them. Only the m-bind function can return those values in some way.